# Mono .NET and C# features

Tags: c#, mono

I am trying to write an agent for the [ACM Queue ICPC challenge](http://queue.acm.org/icpc/overview.cfm)... the instructions say C# agents will be run on linux via mono... which I don't have a ton of experience with.  I try and use features of the most recent versions of C# and .NET (var keyword, linq, etc)... will mono support this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mono C# compiler is considered feature complete for C# 1.0, C# 2.0 and C# 3.0 (ECMA). A preview of C# 4.0 is distributed with Mono 2.6, and a complete C# 4.0 implementation is available with Mono 2.8 or when building Mono from our trunk source code release.

http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler

Also, checking this thread can be helpful:

[The Limitation of Mono Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054397/the-limitation-of-mono-runtime)

Comment: the MoMA tool in the other SO link is great!