# How mature is Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, maturity

How mature is the mono project atm? I've browsed their site but didn't find any indication of how feature complete mono is towards .NET 3.5 / SP1 ?

**Duplicate of [Is Mono Ready for Prime Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450/is-mono-ready-for-prime-time)**

Comment: Why was this closed? "Is mono ready for prime time" was asked 5 months ago. Time for an update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mono is somewhere between .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5
See the mono [faq](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_General)

Comment: so it is in .Net 2.75? :P

Answer (score 5):

See this question, with commentary by none other than mono developer miguel de icaza:
[Is Mono ready for prime time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450/is-mono-ready-for-prime-time/93952#93952)