# Mutliplatform development with C#

Tags: c#, mono, cross-platform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Mono ready for prime time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450/is-mono-ready-for-prime-time)

I have a few questions that are related to each others.

- What strategy do you use for creating applications in C# that work on Windows, Linux and Mac? I know that mono is probably the right tool, but what is your work flow like? Do you develop in Visual Studio and then try to port the result to mono for Linux and Mac, or do you develop directly with mono?
- If I create an app for mono, and I don't use GTK# or Cocoa#, will this compile under VS and run with the .NET framework as well?
- Is Mono stable enough for building commercial applications for B2B and B2C?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450/is-mono-ready-for-prime-time

Comment: Thank you Mehrdad. I searched before posting, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Is Mono ready for prime time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450/is-mono-ready-for-prime-time)
The link provided by @Mehirdad answers some of your question.

I find VS much better than MonoDevelop or the others. I'm sure they'll almost catch up one day. If you stick to System, cross-platform assemblies you'll be pretty good and then porting isn't really necessary, unless you mean testing, since the binaries just work.

Answer (score 1):

I have a server app written in C#, that runs on 64-bit Linux severs.  I do the development in VS2008 and upload the .exe without modification. Yet to experience any compatibility problems.  Fast and stable.

I tried running one of my Winform desktop apps on Linux.  Worked ok, except for the RichText control.

Monodevelop is looking really good now.  I probably wont switch anytme soon, as I have too much time invested in VS. There is a new VS plugin coming out for Mono in the next release, that sounds fantastic.