# mono in production websites?

Tags: mono

I'm investigating the use of mono in real world high traffic web applications. There are some references on the mono site (companies using mono), but I couldn't find a high traffic website sample other than Deki powered ones. And I've read some mailings about mod_mono stability problems because of inexistence of compacting GC.

Please reference your app and give some info, if is there anyone using mono in production.

...or do I have to look at Java ?

Regards,
sirmak

Comment: Consider using Ruby on rails. I've heard it is a good platform for web sites with a tons of request, of course it would depends on hardware configurations and other things but for example: pinterest.com was developed under Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 13):

Wikipedia is using Mono for search (also listed on the [companies using Mono page](http://www.mono-project.com/Companies_Using_Mono))

Answer (score 1):

A ton of people use Mono in production and development. I'm sure this page will change dramatically over the next year or so, but look at http://www.mono-project.com/Companies_Using_Mono. This is a good reference, but projects using Mono are popping up every day, so we'll see more soon.

Answer (score 0):

Lunchwalla.com uses Mono for its website.  It receives fairly high traffic.  There is also a little blog item regarding the set up - http://blog.lunchwalla.com/2010/04/23/the-tech-behind-lunchwalla/

Comment: this reference is not real, even the domain is not active or has a low ranking in Alexa.com

Answer (score 0):

Go for it. Beyond the initial setup work and tuning you can have a very stable and fast server with all the advantages of low-resource required do the the job, at least with nginx/lighttpd. mod_mono (Apache) resources will go way faster according to a lot of feedback I've been reading on the all the major places this topic is discussed

From #mono (IRC)

```
<ruionwriting> ahall: in apache what is your feel about the performance compared with nginx?
<ahall> the fastcgi implementation is just a bit buggy and buy sending few concurrent requests to it it hogged 99% cpu and didn't get out of it. I will switch to nginx + fastcgi as soon as its suitable for me in production
<ahall> buy = by
<ahall> but yeah i always use nginx instead of apache whenever possible, but with mono i dont recommend it
```

This last part I don't have to agree based on the setup I have.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450/is-mono-ready-for-prime-time) on stack overflow must me included here.