# ASP.NET on Mono scalability

Tags: asp.net, performance, mono, scalability

Does anyone know of any ASP.NET Mono production websites that get a substantial amount of traffic - 100 million page views per day, 100-300 page views per second, etc. ? I've searched here and on the HighScalability.com website but didn't find any.

---

To clarify my question - I'm wondering if I deploy my ASP.NET/C# website on the Mono/Apache/Linux stack will it suffer a performance hit over just keeping deployed on the .NET/IIS/Windows Server stack? If I were to deploy the same app on two separate servers with exactly the same hardware config, one server running .NET/IIS/Windows Server and the other running Mono/Apache/Linux, and then do some benchmark testing(load testing, stress testing, etc.), what would the numbers be?

Comment: see also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391813/mono-in-production-websites ?

Comment: Did you read/know ASP.NET on .NET/IIS scalability? I think every basic principles apply to ASP.NET on Mono too (such as load balancing support and so on).

Comment: To clarify my question - I'm wondering if I deploy my ASP.NET/C# website on the Mono/Apache/Linux stack will it suffer a performance hit over just keeping deployed on the .NET/IIS/Windows Server stack? If I were to deploy the same app on two separate servers with exactly the same hardware config, one server running .NET/IIS/Windows Server and the other running Mono/Apache/Linux, and then do some benchmark testing(load testing, stress testing, etc.), what would the numbers be?

Comment: I've seen the list of production websites running Mono. Looks like Wikipedia is the only verifiable high traffic site. However, what kind of traffic numbers does Wikipedia's search functionality get? I mean, whenever I use Wikipedia I almost always get there from a Google search via the URL link to the Wikipedia page. I don't usually use Wikipedia's search box. Maybe 2-3 out of 10 times that I visit. The other times I get to the Wikipedia page from the Google link or to other pages from the links within the Wikipedia page I'm viewing.

Comment: Nonetheless, given Wikipedia's site traffic numbers, its search box probably gets more hits than any other site on that list.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect the same performance numbers for ASP.NET on Mono and Linux as you would expect on Windows. However, things will change with vNext, the next version of ASP.NET, where Mono and Linux are touted to be first class citizens.

Here is a tech power benchmark article that has performance numbers for various web frameworks including mono - http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/

As you can see ASP.NET on Mono is nowhere near the top for any of categories. However, that should not be a showstopper for picking ASP.NET on Mono. It really depends on your set of requirements. i.e. the response times you are trying to meet satisfying a given number of requests per second. ASP.NET on Mono could very well be good enough for your set of requirements. Add to that any productivity gains you and your team will make by using familiar C# and .NET, ASP.NET on Mono may very well work for you.