# What GUI toolkit should I use

Tags: winforms, macos, user-interface, mono, c#-2.0

I have a C# application. Currently all modules are written in .NET 2 and it uses some executables that have linux ports. So I was wondering what toolkit should I use on Windows and MacOS to compile it max easy on both? On Windows Some guys told me that on Windows I can use WinForms, but on Mac I must use MonoMac, but the transition is hard to make. I need something to be done easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port it to Mono (NOT MonoMac) and it should work on both.

http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_Winforms_Applications

You should be able to recompile and run for both platforms once you have completed the port.

Comment: You mean using the starndart Mono WinForms emulation? Many people told me it's not stable.

Comment: It is not an emulation, and it is stable. It is also 100% (or nearly) complete. It is a problem with the software, which uses P/Invoke, not with the mono's implementation.

Comment: You should look at this other article on StackOverflow if you are not yet convinced:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450/is-mono-ready-for-prime-time

Comment: So I can recompile my WinForms app freely if I don't use many pinvokes or check the platform before using them?

Comment: If there are no PInvokes, you don't have to recompile it. You can use the Mono Migration Analyzer (MoMa) to find out, if there will be any problems running on a mono platform.

Comment: Yes, please use the MoMa (http://mono-project.com/MoMA) and let us know if there are any showstopping issues that display from the report.

Comment: It uses WinPCAP and some PInvokes, everything else seems ok. I wonder will I be able to use tcpdump with Process's class and to monitor its output stream on Mac, to replace the WinPcap Stuff there?

Comment: I found windump. I guess I'll use it instead of winpcap. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

[GTK#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp) may be an option. I don't conciser it to be convenient though, but it is a matter of taste.

In my humble opinion, you should use different GUI toolkits for each platform ( this is usually a topic of holy wars, but i think, if your budget is enough for that, you really should consider doing this). I can name only a few completely cross-platform applications, which we written using only one GUI toolkit that really fit all systems altogether.

Comment: GTK is ugly and almost unusable on Windows.

Comment: It is not unusable at all, ugly however.

Comment: GTK+ perfectly usable on Windows. It may look out of place however on Windows, but it's totally usable.